# Write a program to replace all even numbers in an array with $ and print the array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, char, printf

This is my code. And it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int size, i;

    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    printf("Enter array limit: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("Enter values: ");

    int arr[size];

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        if(arr[i]%2==0){
            arr[i]='$';
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
36
3
36
1
```

Comment: trusfated, `printf("%d\n",arr[i]);`prints an integer.   `$` is not an integer.  When the number is even, simply `printf("$\n");`.

Comment: Might be easier if you don't ask input and just generate numbers.

Comment: It has sort of worked. Your array contains ints, when you tried to put $ in it the ASCII value for $ was used instead (which is 36)

Comment: My wager is that the problem statement is "replace even value digits in a char array with '$' (then print the "string")"...

Comment: You might want to ask whoever gave you this task for clarification. In C, arrays which contain integers cannot contain anything else. So it's not clear what this exercise should accomplish. Alternatively, you could use a different language, which allows arrays to contain anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in this for loop

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}
```

output elements storing the character constant `'$'` using the conversion specifier `%c`. For example

```
for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    printf( arr[i] == '$' ? "%c\n", "%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int arr[N] = { '$', 1, '$', 3, '$', 5, '$', 7, '$', 9 };

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( arr[i] == '$' ? "%c\n" : "%d\n", arr[i] );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
1
$
3
$
5
$
7
$
9
```

Or to output elements of the array in a line like

```
$ 1 $ 3 $ 5 $ 7 $ 9
```

you can use the following for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    printf( arr[i] == '$' ? "%c " : "%d ", arr[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the number with the ascii code of the dollar character. You can do one of two things:

Leave the array alone and add an if statement where you print. If even, print the number, else print $

Create an array of char*. Allocate 20 chars for each element if the array. Use sprintf to print the number or $ in each element. Loop and print each element of the new array.

Anycase, you can't store '$' in the int array and then determine that It's a character. It is just a number.